# Text field on focus shift the placeholder at top right corner of any size text field

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a multiple text field of different size with a placeholder. When I type on a text field, the placeholder text is displayed at the top right corner of text field of any size. But the code I tried below, the placeholder of specific text field on which I type is moving along with placeholder text from other text field as well.

I dont know where I did mistake. Can anybody help me through this.

Thank you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.inputWrap').removeClass('activate');
  $('.inputText').on('keyup', function() {
    if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
      $('.inputWrap').addClass('activate');
    };
  });
  $('.inputText').on('focusout', function() {
    if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
      $('#inputWrap').addClass('activate');
    } else {
      $('.inputWrap').removeClass('activate');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#inputWrap {
  position: relative;
}

.activate .floating-label {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: none;
  transform: none;
  color: #ddd;
}

.floating-label {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 195px;
  top: 5px;
  transition: 0.2s ease all;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(3px);
  transform: translateY(3px);
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 11px;
}

.activate input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inputWrap">
  <input type="text" name="email" size="35" class="inputText" required value="" placeholder="Email">
  <span class="floating-label">Email</span>
</div>

<div class="inputWrap">
  <input type="text" class="inputText" required value="" placeholder="Address" />
  <span class="floating-label">Address</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.inputWrap {
  position: relative;
}

.activate .floating-label {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: none;
  transform: none;
  color: #ddd;
}

.floating-label {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 195px;
  top: 5px;
  transition: 0.2s ease all;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(3px);
  transform: translateY(3px);
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 11px;
}

.activate input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inputWrap">
  <input type="text" name="email" size="35" class="inputText" required value="" placeholder="Email"/>
  <span class="floating-label">Email</span>
</div>

<div class="inputWrap">
  <input type="text" class="inputText" required="required" value="" placeholder="Address" />
  <span class="floating-label">Address</span>
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.inputWrap').removeClass('activate');
            $('.inputText').on('keyup', function () {
                $(this).parents('.inputWrap:first').toggleClass('activate', $(this).val().length > 0);
            });
            $('.inputText').on('blur', function () {
                $(this).parents('.inputWrap:first').toggleClass('activate', $(this).val().length > 0);
            });
        });        
    </script>
```